# QGIS Print Composer - one layer spills outside the Map Frame when printing or saving to PDF

Tags: qgis, print-composer

New to QGIS and using QGIS 3.28

I have created a print layout which looks fine in the print composer - see image 1, however when I export to PDF or print the map, one of my layers spills outside of the map box frame see image 2. All of the other layers are OK.

I have tried Lock layers and Lock styles for Layers and the extents are set to the map bounds.

I have searched for similar issues in several forums with no success.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2 with layer overspill]

The layer that overspills is an edited ESRI OSM original GL style sheet, from [arcgis VectorTileServer](https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/OpenStreetMap_v2/VectorTileServe)

Comment: There is a clipping setting in the layout properties you might fiddle with.  One way to get to it is click the far right small icon across the top in the map's item properties panel.

Comment: Thanks - that worked